Analyzing facial deformation using mediapipe's facial landmark model
I'm doing a study trying to analyze facial deformation energy after receiving a punch for a study.
The problem is, that I'm finding it hard to measure it accurately. The simplest thing is to measure how much all 468 points move, but the issue is that the head also moves after receiving a strike, and all I want to study is how much the face itself changes during a strike.
Does anyone have any creative ways to do this? How do we study the facial landmarks changing while accounting for the head moving?
I'm not sure how to even approach this problem.
I'm using retroactive videos of past UFC fights. I have attached one data source to this:
https://streamable.com/j3a48w

those AI face landmark detectors just guess those points, and these detectors tend towards "normal" faces, so the points will never move in any way that conforms to someone getting punched. they will never ever accurately track the points on someone's skin.

you could pay some bums to sharpie lots of little dots on their faces and beat each other up. with a bunch of high speed high resolution cameras pointed at them. and intense light all around, against motion blur. you'll also have to mount registration markers for intraoperative navigation to their skulls for tracking.
